# Need some help about a layover in Shanghai

Tags: visas

I have Ecuadorian and US passports. I am doing a trip to Thailand but on the way I have a 13-hour layover in Shanghai and I want to look around the city. Can I do that without a visa? And what would be the process to do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: While your flight is permissible it's possible you will have trouble with airline clerks that do not understand.  Go to TIMATIC (United airlines has a portal, I'm sure there are other ways but I do not know them) and make a printout of the rules and allow plenty of extra time at check-in in case you run into someone who thinks they know the rules and won't check.  There have been multiple cases of improperly denied boarding from clerks who are sure you need a visa.

Comment: And there also have been clerks who don't truly understand the rules about tricky situations (US -> China (5 days) -> Japan (2 hours) -> US) and don't understand the admittedly confusing TIMATIC output.  (The stated itinerary is legal but will only show as such if you enter it as a trip to Japan with a stopover in China.)

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need a [transit visa](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-144hour.htm). Travelers with US passports can stay in Shanghai for up to 144 hours visa free. You'll need to do the following:

> 1. Inform the carrier when boarding
> 2. Fill an Arrival/Departure Card
> 3. Apply for the 144-hour visa-free stay permit upon arrival
> 4. Claim the luggage
> 5. Go through the customs
> 6. Leave the airport

Comment: No, he's not going to get a 144 hour permit.  Given the stated flight schedule he's going to get a 24 hour permit.

Comment: @LorenPechtel It's the same visa & visa counter, even if it's issued with a lower validity period.